# Rmagick Imagemagick error in rails - Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libMagickCore.4.dylib (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, rmagick

6.8
with brew

Trying to use Rmagick but I keep getting this error:

> /Sites/woo/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': dlopen(/Users/myname/Sites/woo/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/RMagick2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libMagickCore.4.dylib (LoadError)

I tried installing and reinstalling imagemagick and Rmagick with no luck. I also tried gem pristine rmagick.

probably a path problem since cd /opt/local/lib/ doesn't exist.

Anyone knows how to handle this?